# Treeview node reselection

Tags: c#-2.0

I'm working on compact framework 2.0 and using c#.
I have problem with treeview node reselection. Scenario is like this :
temp0
temp1
temp2
temp3
I have some node in treeview and using up and down arrow for moving node up and down.
but problem is that once i select a node and clicking up arrow, node is moved up
and I cann't select node just below this node.
Suppose I select temp3 and press up arrow, this temp3 is replaced by temp2.
like this:
temp0
temp1
temp3
temp2
after this I cann't select temp2 but able to select temp3 and other node whatever is up.

---

I'm using this code for up arrow:

int paramPos = this.treeView1.SelectedNode.Index;

if (paramPos > 0)

{

System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode tempNode = this.treeView1.SelectedNode;

this.treeView1.Nodes[paramPos] = this.treeView1.Nodes[paramPos - 1];

this.treeView1.Nodes[paramPos - 1] = tempNode;

this.treeView1.SelectedNode = this.treeView1.Nodes[paramPos - 1];

foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode tnode in this.treeView1.Nodes)

{

ArgumentNumberInfo ai = (ArgumentNumberInfo)tnode.Tag;

ai.ArgNo = tnode.Index + 1;

```
}

                  treeView1.SelectedNode = tempNode;
                  this.treeView1_AfterSelect(null, null);


            }
        }
```

After pressing up arrow node is going to up but i cann't able to select node below this.
Node0

node1

node2

node3

If you select node3 and click on up arrow node3 will go up and node2 will come down but you cann't select node2.
please give me some clue why is it happening.
Thnx for your time.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include the actual code that modifies the treeview please?

Comment: for up arrow I'm using this code:

Answer (score 1):

Treeview nodes are maintained by an internal linked list.  I think the method that you're using to swap them around is confusing that linked list.  Here's the part of the code that I'm referring to:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode tempNode = this.treeView1.SelectedNode;
this.treeView1.Nodes[paramPos] = this.treeView1.Nodes[paramPos - 1];
this.treeView1.Nodes[paramPos - 1] = tempNode;
```

Try the following in place of the code above:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode tempNode = this.treeView1.SelectedNode;
this.treeView1.Remove(tempNode);
this.treeView1.Insert(paramPos - 1, tempNode);
```